# Cannot import AAR from golang into my app (tried previous answers but they do not work)

Tags: android, android-studio, go, aar, gomobile

I am trying to make a golang package that can be included in an Android app.

So I have

- created a golang module and built it using go bind to an aar
- used 'new module' in Android Studio to import the aar
- gone to project structure/dependencies/... to connect up the aar, *but* the aar was not listed so I could not add it.
- the module appears to be in android/mobile; how do I tell Android Studio? Do I need to?

So

- does anyone know what the *exact* command line is that I need for go bind? Assuming, say that I am trying for a module 'mobile' in a project 'hk.nurke.fred'.
- also, how do I refer to my package in the java import statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your file in lib folder then import it by using it

```
compile( name : 'Name of AAR' , ext : 'aar' )
```

and

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Check it i hope you get solution

Comment: Sorry, in which files do I put the above code? What are the file paths?

Comment: @MartinEllison how did you fix it?
I have the same issue, I have a large .aar file generated by gomobile, when I import it its imports but I can see it as a module
however I tried a simple hello world gomobile .aar and it works ok

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue today. Apparently the writer forgot to mention this in the doc [Mobile#building-and-deploying-to-android](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile#building-and-deploying-to-android-1).

Below is the missing step:

1. copy "yourgolangmodule.aar" and "yourgolangmodule.jar" to "yourreactnativeproject\android\app";
2. in "yourreactnativeproject\android\app\build.gradle" file, add below:

(**how to get the clue: compare between this file in the example project from doc and the one in your project.**)

[image]

3. click File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files